# AS3 ERROR : Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2036: Load Never Completed

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Hi I am new to as3 and have a problem with a site im developing. It all runs fine on my local file but after I upload to a server and run I get the error 
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2036: Load Never Completed.
 Can anybode give me an idea of what I am doing wrong please ? I know that the problem is with 6 images that load from an XML file to the front page. On my server version on one picture loads . Here is what I believe is my problematic code

```
// panel pictures and text  

        for (var thm:Number = 0;  thm< my_total ;  thm++ ){
        var thumb_url = my_images[thm].@PANEL ;
        var thumb_loader = new Loader();
        thumb_loader.load(new URLRequest(thumb_url));
        ximage[thm] = new MovieClip 
        ximage[thm].addChild(thumb_loader);
        ximage[thm].x = -38
        ximage[thm].y = - 150 
        ximage[thm].alpha = 0.8


        } // for 
        myXMLLoader = null;
```

Later on in the code I addChild and get the pictures on the page. I know that this code works locally. If it helps anyone here is a link to my server flash program . If you look you can see the idea and that only one image loads before the error. 
[Flash Program link](http://www.abbeysoft.co.uk/DCP/DaveCowelPhotography.html)  Thanks for looking at my problem I hope someone can point me in the right direction . Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URLs for the images your movie is trying to load produce 404 errors, e.g. http://abbeysoft.co.uk/DCP/opener/blackwhite.JPG. You need to lowercase the filename extensions in your XML file, e.g. http://abbeysoft.co.uk/DCP/opener/blackwhite.jpg

Comment: Thanks a lot for that - all is well now !!